# downloading a torrent file using uTorrent in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, utorrent, torrent-client

So when I feed a torrent URL it doesn't get downloaded. How do you exactly feed a URL to get downloaded in utorrent? I need to download the English Wikipedia for NLP Research and they have provided a torrent file for download in their github page. My torrent server is running in Ubuntu 14.04 (and I have downloaded the utorrent for 13.04 because there was none for 14.04):
https://github.com/idio/wiki2vec/raw/master/torrents/enwiki-gensim-word2vec-1000-nostem-10cbow.torrent
[image]

server running:
mona@pascal:~$ utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/

I pastes the URL and then clicked OK and nothing happened.

Comment: "URL" in the context of bittorent means a *magnet link* and yet the link (URL) you posted above is of an actual torrent file which is intended to be downloaded and opened by the torrent client. PS - Most Ubuntu flavors come with one of the best torrent clients already - Transmission -, Kubuntu being the exception with KTorrent which is also very good (and Transmission can be installed from the official repositories as well). There's no need to go out of your way to install third party software for the purpose.

Comment: @CelticWarrior: Since all Ubuntu flavours share the same repositories one can install Transmission in Kubuntu just as well as in any other flavour. It even has a nice Qt interface if you don't like to run GTK+ applications in KDE.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with CelticWarrior's comment: it would be healthy to use KTorrent (full of features) or Transmission (simple interface).

In any case, to actually get your download started you probably need to use the menu: `File -> Open` and then find the `.torrent` file you downloaded.